# Eclipse java project where directory structure != package structure

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I would like to use Eclipse to work on a Java project where the directory structure does not correspond entirely to the package structure.

For example, source files in the package `a.b.c` are located in the directory `x/y/c`. The name of the leaf package (`c`) always corresponds to the name of the immediately containing directory (also `c`), but their prefixes may be different (`a.b` versus `x/y`).

(I think the project's build system copies the source files into a directory structure that corresponds to the package structure, but I need to operate on the original files, not the copied files.)

When I look at source files in this project in Eclipse, I see errors of the form `The declared package "a.b.c" does not match the expected package "x.y.c"`, and it is also unable to resolve imports of the form `import a.b.foo`. How can I inform Eclipse of the mapping from `x/y` to `a.b` and get rid of these errors?

**Please do not suggest any solution that involves changing the package declarations or moving the files around. I cannot do either.**

Comment: This is the way Java works.  You can't change that.  You cannot get rid of the errors without changing languages.  C# uses namespaces that don't depend on directory structure.  Try rewriting as C#.

Comment: You'll have to use a build file.

Comment: @DaveNewton: How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in Java, the runtime system always looks for a/b/c as directory structure for a specific class in package a.b.c. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.4

Comment: The code in question belongs to a large open-source project (Mozilla). Surely they know what they are doing?

Comment: Also, I'm not at all convinced that this being the behaviour of the **Java runtime system** implies it's impossible to teach **Eclipse** the path translations.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question correctly: You have a class, a.b.c.ClassName and you want to put it in a directory x/y/c/ClassName.jva[class]? 
Maybe you did specify the source root for the project wrong, this can cause these kind of problems.

Comment: Let me give a specific example: in the source code distribution, there is a file located at `mobile/android/base/gfx/GeckoLayerClient.java`. The file's package declaration is `package org.mozilla.gecko.gfx;`. Eclipse complains: `The declared package "org.mozilla.gecko.gfx" does not match the expected package "mobile.android.base.gfx"`.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the only option is to create a default "ANT" target, which will copy the contents from `x\y\c` to `a\b\c`. Attach this ANT target with the Eclipse build. In addition, use `a\b\c` as java source and remove `x\y\c` from source as it will result into compilation error.

This will allow you to work in the files residing in `x\y\c` but immediately copy and use them from `a\b\c`.

Use: [ANT copy](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html), [Ant copyDir](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copydir.html) and [Ant Compile/Javac](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) task details for further reference.

Comment: If I remove `x/y/c` from source, doesn't that mean that I open some file `Foo.java` in eclipse, it will open `a/b/c/Foo.java` rather than `x/y/z/Foo.java`? I don't want that.

Comment: You can always use "open resource" option (CTRL+SHIFT+R) to open the files from x/y/z.

Comment: Or use an `ANT` target to copy first and compile from to copied folder and disable the default build from Eclipse. This way you can work on x\y\z but behind the scene, it will use a\b\c.